# Как считать информацию из карт Google?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Есть задача — нужно достать данные из Google Maps (отдельно взятый периметр) об организациях (название и его "категорию").

Вопрос собственно в том, какие сервисы Google в этом помогут?

Comment: Не очень понял вопроса, Вы хотите достать данные об определённых организация по Вашему запросу?

Comment: @Maxim Shinkarev именно так, вдобавок определить географические границы  для этих организаций, как я понял нужно использовать Google Places API